# Strange behaviour of Bool variable in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

I am observing a weird behaviour in Julia 1.0. I have a boolean variable, which is set to `true`. The problem is, its negation is also `true` ... :-\

The code is as follows:

```
my_var = my_func(....)
println("my_var ", my_var, 
    ' ', !my_var,
    ' ', bitstring(my_var),
    ' ', typeof(my_var))
```

This prints

```
my_var true true 00000000 Bool
```

This code is located inside a package that I am developing. `my_func` has two methods, both of which return a `Bool`. This problem manifests itself only when one of the methods is used, the other one works fine. Both methods of `my_func` go like this:

```
function my_func(arg::SomeType) # or arg::SomeOtherType
    ....
    return true
end
```

This works the same in 0.7 and 1.0. There is no such problem in 0.6. Has anyone come across anything like this?

Comment: That looks very much like a bug.  Please report it on the Julia issue tracker — ideally with the definition of `my_func` (or a limited version thereof) so we can better reproduce it.  https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/new

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29805

Comment: Can you provide a minimum complete `my_func` definition? I tried several definitions and cannot reproduce the behaviour.